# Can I safely remove .BAK files from mysql database?

Tags: mysql, file, drupal, delete-file

When I look inside my Drupal 6 database on a Linux machine, I see that it is clutters with a bunch of very big *.BAK files, with names like cache_form-110416043841.BAK. I am wondering if I can safely delete them? And if deleting them is not recommended, what's their use?

Comment: Where, specifically, are the files located?

Comment: They are inside the database folder, along with .frm and .MYI files/tables.

Comment: Actually I removed all the .BAK files from the database and apparently no harm inured to my site. However, I am still unclear about these .BAK files: Why they are created and how can I avoid them to grow these big.

Comment: Perhaps that is just where your host is storing your database backups.  I'm not aware of anything standard that creates those, but .bak is a fairly standard name for database backup files.

Comment: It is not on a shared host. I guess you are right that they should be backup files.

Comment: You have tagged this as a “Drupal” item, but I don’t believe that it is specific to or isolated to your Drupal configuration. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at your **/etc/my.cnf** file and you’ll probably see this line:

```
myisam-recover = BACKUP
```

Or, if you're using a more recent version of MySQL:

```
myisam-recover-options = BACKUP
```

This is an option for the MyISAM storage engine. With recovery enabled, when MySQL starts up if it detects that a MyISAM table crashed or otherwise was not closed properly, it attempts to automatically recover the table. With the **BACKUP** option, it also creates this .BAK file of a copy of the table before it attempted recovery.

If everything seems to be running fine after a safe margin of time (30 days? YMMV), personally, I’d feel comfortable deleting the older .BAK files*, but if there are a lot of these over a span of time that continues to the present, I would probably try to identify the underlying problem that results in the failure of the tables being properly closed.

- [Related MySQL Documentation](http://www.google.com/search?q=%2B%22server+command+options%22+%2B%22myisam-recover%22+site:dev.mysql.com%2Fdoc%2Frefman)

*The age of the BAK file can be determined by a simple stat command or by the timestamp encoded in the file’s name: `table-YYMMDDHHMMSS.BAK`

Comment: Thanks, but how to identify their ages?